# RPI Native Build Qt 5.10.1: config test architecture failure

Tags: qt5, native, raspberry-pi3

Hi I am trying to build QT 5.10.1 with [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204529). I am getting this error;

```
    Command line: -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-vc4-g++ -device-option 
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /opt/qt5pi/sysroot -prefix 
/usr/local/qt5pi -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwebengine -skip 
qtscript -nomake examples -no-use-gold-linker -make libs -v
executing config test architecture
+ cd /home/pi/qt5build/config.tests/arch && 
/home/pi/qt5build/qtbase/bin/qmake "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release 
app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" 
"QMAKE_CFLAGS += --sysroot=/opt/qt5pi/sysroot" "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --
sysroot=/opt/qt5pi/sysroot" "QMAKE_LFLAGS += --sysroot=/opt/qt5pi/sysroot" -
early "CONFIG += cross_compile" /home/pi/qt-everywhere-src-
5.10.1/qtbase/config.tests/arch
 + cd /home/pi/qt5build/config.tests/arch && MAKEFLAGS= /usr/bin/make clean 
&& MAKEFLAGS= /usr/bin/make
> rm -f arch.o
> rm -f *~ core *.core
> arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=crypto-
neon-
fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/opt/qt5pi/sysroot -O2 -w -fPIC  -
I/home/pi/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1/qtbase/config.tests/arch -I. -
I/home/pi/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-
pi3-vc4-g++ -o arch.o /home/pi/qt-everywhere-src-
5.10.1/qtbase/config.tests/arch/arch.cpp
> /home/pi/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1/qtbase/config.tests/arch/arch.cpp:43:19: 
fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
>  #include <stdio.h>
>                    ^
> compilation terminated.
> Makefile:179: recipe for target 'arch.o' failed
> make: *** [arch.o] Error 1
```

I checked the include file in the /usr location it is there. If I add the file arch.cpp location then it needs another file. How can I fix this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

`fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory`

This suggests you are missing build dependencies on your host machine (the machine on which you are running `configure`), most likely *libc*

I'm not sure what package manager you have, but with `apt` you can install this with:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev
```

Failing that, you also might like to try:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

which installs various compilation tools/libraries.